# Just installed Lubuntu 17.04 to try it. All is well, except my keyboard volume keys do nothing

Tags: sound, keyboard, lubuntu

The **Sound Settings** button on the panel app is also unresponsive, but it does open via PulseAudio. It's an HP 2000 laptop. I also have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it, and the volume keys work fine on that OS. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so I am stumped.

Comment: Try the solutions presented here: https://askubuntu.com/a/907692/103537