# Keyboard volume control stopped working

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, volume-control

Running Xubuntu (actually Ubuntu Studio) 18.04 LTS on a Toshiba Sattelite p850

Until recently I could control volume by `Fn + F9/F10/F11` but the function stopped working. Other keys in combination with the Function key `Fn` still works as expected, eg `Fn + F6/F8` makes Clementine skip to previous or next track in the playlist while `Fn + F4` brings up the Display dialog.

I can't think of anything unusual I did, installing updates when they appear in software updater.

I tried searching several forums and found similar problems, but most of them seem to be with Unity which I am not using.

From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610786/volume-hot-key-not-working-in-lubuntu) I tried

```
xfce4-volumed
```

which gave a lot of error messages like `Binding 'XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!`, `Binding 'XF86AudioMute' failed!` and `Binding 'XF86AudioRaiseVolume' failed!`

In the Settings Editor I can not find any XF86 properties for Audio, the closest thing is `XF86Music` which has the value `parole`.

```
xev
```

gives

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  75  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

for volume down and

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

for volume up.

So how do I regain the missing keyboard bindings?

Edit: I also found a related question in an [arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188076) that says it's possible to add shortcuts through the settings editor, but I don't understand which property or what value to use...

Comment: This is primarily a FYI:  Ubuntu Studio was **not** a LTS release; so it's updates are not SRU'd and released thru normal channels, but extended support (equal to a LTS release) are available via PPA.  This may mean if you didn't add the PPA, your Ubuntu Studio components haven't been upgraded with fixes (security & other) If you're not using the Ubuntu Studio PPA for 18.04, I'd suggest adding it - https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and added the PPA some time ago. Maybe I should have said 'semi-LTS' in the post :-)

Comment: It appears your volume keys are working (the keystrokes are intercepted by xfce4-volumed) but they're likely pointing at the wrong audio output "track". If you open `pavucontrol` (which you may have to install, `apt install pavucontrol`), I suspect your volume buttons are merely tethered to the wrong output device; bring the volume up and down and see which Output Device is modified. [Ubuntu bug 883485](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-volumed/+bug/883485) or [Debian bug 677014](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=677014) may help you, though they did not help me.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and found that I was using the rather old xfce4-volumed rather than its modern replacement, xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin. I removed the old program and installed the new one (`sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`), then I added the PulseAudio Panel Plugin to one of my XFCE4 panels: Right-click on a border or separator, go to **Panel**, then **Add New Items**. Search for "pulse" and double-click on the PulseAudio Plugin. (See left window in screenshot.)

[image: screen shot]

Right-click on the volume icon you just added to your panel and go to **Properties** (see right window in screenshot). Ensure "Enable Keyboard shortcuts for volume control" is checked. Now click <kbd>Run Audio Mixer…</kbd> to launch pavucontrol (you may need to `sudo apt install pavucontrol` first).

Click on the **Output Devices** tab and enlarge the window so all of your devices are visible without needing to scroll. Now press your keyboard's volume keys (<kbd>︎</kbd> and <kbd>︎</kbd>) a bunch. You should see one of those sliders start moving left and right. That means everything works, but the system doesn't know which speaker to control (Pulseaudio doesn't have a "Master" channel the way Alsa does).

Now, get to the command line and run `pactl list short sinks`. You'll see an indexed list of your output devices ("sinks"). Select the one you want, say `3`, and then set it to be the default with `pacmd set-default-sink 3`.

Now tinker with your keyboard's <kbd>︎</kbd> and <kbd>︎</kbd> keys some more. You should see the desired slider moving in pavucontrol, and if you're playing some music, you should hear the difference.